# How to use Laravel Mail from Controller with Vue Component

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, email

I'm searching a way to get the vue component through `realpath()` method from `php controller` and trying to send a `php variable` to that `component`. But I can't get it.

From my previous case when I'm using `php` only I can do this.

```
$data= array('email_message'=>
 "<p style='text-align:center; color:black'>The setup process is very easy, simply click the link below and click save.</p>
  <p style='text-align:center;'><a style='text-align:center;' href='http://localhost/invite/email/$token'>Start Enrollment</a></p>"
);

Mail::send('template.invite_email',$data, function($message) 
use ($email,$subject){
   $message->from('noreply@foobar.com','Foo Bar');
   $message->to($some_email)->subject($some_subject);
});
```

Then Inside `template_invite.email`

```
<div align="center" class="main-content">
   {!!$email_message!!}
</div>
```

And with my new case here's what I'm trying to do with `vue` and trying to replace the `template_invite.email` with this variable and passing the `$email_message` to that `component`

```
$path = realpath('C:\xampp\htdocs\foo-vue\resources\js\components\template\email\InviteEmail.vue');
```

Comment: Emails can't contain Vue components. Since Vue is Javascript and executed client-side, most email clients block its execution

Comment: I see, do you have a suggestion or maybe library that I can use? I'm still newbie with these technologies and keep on learning it.

Comment: I know it's a lot, but I'd recommend reading through the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#introduction

Comment: Why do you want to use vue in an email? its an email. just use the default markup. unless theres a specific reason.

Comment: Previously our template is in the blade file, but this time we're doing the new project that has no blade file and all the codes are in vue now.